# For prime numbers $p_n$ it holds $m\equiv p_n^2\pmod {p_{n+1}}\implies$ $m$ is a square

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, conjectures, square-numbers

Conjecture about primes:

> For all $n\notin\{4,9,30\}$ it holds that if $m\equiv p_n^2\pmod
> {p_{n+1}}$ where $0 \leq m < p_{n+1}$, then $m$ is a square.

Tested for $n<1,000,000$.

The only exceptions seems to be $p_4=7$, $p_9=23$ and $p_{30}=113$.

Would like help to prove, explain or contradict this.

Comment: What's the question?  Obviously $p_n^2$ is a square.

Comment: I suspect the OP is considering "mod" as a binary operation rather than as a ternary predicate....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  Sorry?  Not following,

Comment: @Lehs  of course it is. It is the square of $p_4$.

Comment: I have no idea what binary operation means in this context.  Please explain.

Comment: @Lehs Indeed. People who use "mod" as a binary operation are on my little list :-)

Comment: Lehs-- So $p_4^2=49,$ which mod 11 gives $5$ (not square). Is that the idea?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: good grief! Your little list includes everybody who programs in Pascal or Ada or ... The poor souls have no choice, so please be kind to them.

Comment: I've corrected the question.

Comment: @RobArthan My method is very merciful :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true if either $p_n^2<p_{n+1}$ (obviously) or if $(p_{n+1}-p_n)^2<p_{n+1}$ (because these two squares are congruent mod $p_{n+1}$, since $(-1)^2\equiv 1$). Since a number only has two square roots (or none) modulo a prime, these are the only possibilities.

So the statement is equivalent to the gaps between consecutive primes being less than the square root of the higher prime. This being true in general is basically [Oppermann's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppermann%27s_conjecture) (what we need is very slightly stronger, see comments), so it's a deep unsolved problem.

Comment: Out of interest, how does this align with the exceptions (7, 23 and 113) mentioned in the question?

Comment: Oppermann says there is a prime between $n^2$ and $n^2-n$ for integer $n$, whereas what we need is a prime between $p$ and $p-\sqrt p$. So they are not quite the same, and it's technically possible that if Oppermann's conjecture was only barely true that there would be more counterexamples than this. But it seems likely that it's true with lots to spare as you go higher up.

Comment: e.g. Opperman says there is a prime between $121-\sqrt{121}$ and $121$, which there is. But what we'd need is a prime between $127-\sqrt{127}$ and $127$, which there isn't.

Comment: So it's a slight strengthening of Opperman's conjecture? Maybe that's worth recording in your answer.

Comment: Isn't there a flaw in your argumentation? What if neither $p_n^2<p_{n+1}$ nor $(p_{n+1}-p_n)^2<p_{n+1}$?

Comment: @Lehs then $m$ is not a square, since those are the smallest two squares congruent to $m$ mod $p_{n+1}$.

Comment: Note that if $k^2\equiv p_n^2$ mod $p_{n+1}$ then $(k-p_n)(k+p_n)\equiv 0$, and since $p_{n+1}$ is prime it follows that $k\equiv p_n$ or $k\equiv p_{n+1}-p_n$.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime: Thanks! Number theory is a jungle for me. I never read a single course.