# All even squares are congruent with a prime square $p_n^2\pmod {p_{n+1}}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, square-numbers

A conjecture about primes related to the question
 [For prime numbers $p_n$ it holds $m\equiv p_n^2\pmod {p_{n+1}}\implies$ $m$ is a square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2643802/for-prime-numbers-p-n-it-holds-m-equiv-p-n2-pmod-p-n1-implies-m-is-a)

> For every even $m>0$ there is a $n\in \mathbb Z_+$ such that 
>   $m^2\equiv p_n^2\pmod {p_{n+1}}$, $0\leq m^2<p_{n+1}$.

Tested for $m\leq 152$.

Are there some heuristics about this? Or counterexamples?

Comment: This is almost the same as each even number occurring as a prime gap.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: How come?

Comment: He said *almost*...

Comment: @user477343: And he might be right, but I don't see it.

Comment: If $$m^2\equiv p_n^2\pmod{p_{n+1}}$$ then $$p_{n+1}\mid (p_n + m)(p_n - m).$$ Since $m$ is even and $m > 0$, there is a chance that $p_n \pm m$ is a prime, particularly $$p_{n+1} = p_n\pm m.$$ Of course though $p_n < p_{n+1}$ so $p_{n+1} - p_n > 0$ and therefore we consider $$p_{n+1} = p_n + m$$ or $$p_{n+1} - p_n = m.$$ This is what @LordSharktheUnknown means by his comment, but perhaps $p_n + m$ is not prime, or not equal to $p_{n+1}$, so we add an *almost* to the statement.

Comment: @user477343: Good enough, why don't make it into an answer?

Comment: I see that you like to make conjectures by the way. Perhaps one day you might make a conjecture turning out to be quite the challenge to prove :)

Comment: @user477343: It might happen, if my conjectures are random enough. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$m^2\equiv p_n^2\pmod{p_{n+1}}$$ then $$p_{n+1}\mid (p_n + m)(p_n - m).$$ Since $m$ is even and $m > 0$, there is a chance that $p_n \pm m$ is a prime, particularly $$p_{n+1} = p_n\pm m.$$ Of course though $p_n < p_{n+1}$ so $p_{n+1} - p_n > 0$ and therefore we consider $$p_{n+1} = p_n + m$$ or $$p_{n+1} - p_n = m.$$ So if we can prove that every even number is the difference of two adjacent primes, we prove your conjecture. Also, $p_n - m > 0$ and therefore $p_n > m$.